# Django 1.8: access current user (extended) in ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-1.8, limit-choices-to

**UPDATE**

I tried to use [CuserMiddleware](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cuser) and used it like this to get the current user:

```
 def limit_by_username():
     c_username = ""
     c_user = CuserMiddleware.get_user()
     if c_user is not None:
         c_username = c_user[0].username
     return {'reviewer__user__username__exact':c_username}

 r_list_of_reviews = models.ForeignKey('Review', blank=True, null=True, limit_choices_to=limit_by_username())
```

But still, the list of reviews are not yet displayed
Again, any ideas are greatly appreciated.

**END UPDATE**

I'm using/extending the django Admin site. I'm having a problem in restricting and displaying all the reviews related to a particular reviewer. I've used **limit_choices_to** and the [ThreadLocal.get_current_user() from django_tools](https://github.com/jedie/django-tools/blob/master/django_tools/middlewares/ThreadLocal.py), but it's not working, and the review objects for a particular reviewer are not displayed. Below are my models:

```
class Reviewer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    r_user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    r_list_of_reviews = models.ForeignKey('Review', blank=True, null=True, limit_choices_to={'reviewer__r_user__username__exact': ThreadLocal.get_current_user()})

class Review(models.Model):
    USER_RATING = (
            (1, '1'),
            (2, '2'),
            (3, '3'),
            (4, '4'),
            (5, '5'),
    )
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey('Reviewer')
    review_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_RATING, default=0)
```

Any ideas on how to do this right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might be having typos in `limit_by_username()`. Lookup key should probably say `'reviewer__r_user__username__exact'`, and `c_user[0]` should be just `c_user` since according to middleware implementation it can’t be anything list-like.

By the way, you could construct your choices for the field by hooking up into [`ModelAdmin.get_form()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form). That method has access to request and thus current user. That would be my choice, and also the more Django-y way compared to thread locals (which is what `CuserMiddleware` uses).

Comment: thank you very much for your input Anton. I will try this and will give you a feedback